# How to employ Learning-to-rank models (CNN, LSTM) in short-pair ranking?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, conv-neural-network, information-retrieval, recurrent-neural-network

In common applied learn-to-rank tasks, the inputs are usually semantic and have good syntactic structure, like Question-Answer ranking tasks. In this scenario, CNN or LSTM is a good structure to capture the latent information (local or long dependency) of QA-pairs.

But in reality, sometimes we just have short pair and discrete words. In this occasion, CNN or LSTM is still a fair choice？Or is there some more appropriate method can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigger question is how much training data you have. There's a lot of interesting work, but the reason that the deep neural network approaches tend to use QA ranking tasks is because those tasks typically have hundreds of thousands or millions of training examples.

When you have shorter queries, i.e. title or web queries, you will possibly need even more data to learn, because less of the network will be exercised by each training instance. It is possible, but the method you choose should be based on the training data you have available, rather than the size of your queries, in general.

- [0-50 queries] -> Hand-tuned, time-tested model such as Query Likelihood, BM25, (or if you want better results, ngram models such as SDM) (if you want more recall, pseudo-relevance-feedback models such as RM3).
- [50-1000 queries] -> Linear or Tree-based learning-to-rank methods
- [1000-millions] -> Deep approach, or possibly still learning-to-rank. I'm not sure any of the deep papers have truly dominated a state-of-the-art gradient-boosted-regression-tree setup.

A recent paper by one of my labmates used [pseudo-labels from BM25 to bootstrap a DNN](http://hamedz.ir/blog/how-to-train-deep-learning-models-when-you-dont-have-enough-training-data/). They got good results (better than BM25), but they literally had to be Google (training-time-wise) to pull it off.

Comment: Thx, it makes sense that amounts of data determine the effectiveness of NN